# Costs of expanding an associative array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Because finding a node with JQuery has a significant cost, I built a very simple function

```
window.selectorToObject = {}

function get(selector){
    if(typeof selector === "undefined") 
      return null;
    if(selector in window.selectorToObject) 
      return window.selectorToObject[selector];
    window.selectorToObject[selector] = $(selector);
    return $(selector);
}
```

So then instead of doing `$(selector)` we will simply to `get(selector)`.

After a simple test, the differences are significant:

```
<div id="test">
  <div id="child1">
    <div id="child2">
       <div id="child3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Now I am just worry about the size of the associative array that will grow at each new `get()`.

Is there any costs of expanding a size of an associative array in Javascript?

Comment: Technically an object, not an associative array, in JS.

Comment: But you're still performing the `$()` twice in the first instance - which is once more than any jQuery code block would if the selector is then cached in a variable - as it should always be if it's being used multiple times. In theory there should be no performance difference at all between this and some well written jQuery. Can you please link to your jsperf test.

Comment: Is your page really so large that this is a practical issue? Don't succumb to premature optimization. If you can't perceive a slowdown in your document, don't waste your time trying to bypass it.

Comment: How often are you accessing the same selector? Of course the jsPerf test will show a huge difference, but are you really going to access the same element a million times (or so)?

Comment: This sounds like a bug waiting to happen as soon as you do anything dynamic on the page. It would be much clearer to cache the selector results somewhere close to where they're used.

Answer (score 2):

This will only help if you are making a large number of calls to the same selector.  If you are doing this, then yes it could help, but you should be caching accesses in a locally scoped variable if they are exactly the same anyway.

However, you also **break the selector** in the case of dynamic content.  If you call `get('.mydiv')` and then add another `<div class="mydiv"></div>` later, `get()` will return an object with the latest `div` missing.

As you alluded to, there is also a memory cost here.  You are trading speed for memory footprint.  In general, this is not an issue, but neither is the performance of jQuery selectors unless you are doing a huge number of selector calls.

Practically speaking, I doubt anyone would have a need for this.  Don't go for optimization unless it is truly an issue.  You should always have a mind toward writing good code, but resist the urge to over-optimize.

Comment: I agree here, but one thing to add is in my experience if your page is making so many calls with the same selector then you probably can benefit more by using a variable scoped in some enclosure to store the selector on an individual use basis rather than using your method to cache the jquery objects.

Comment: @codefactor: Agreed. That's what I was implying by "caching accesses if they are exactly the same", but I probably wasn't clear enough.  Edited.